# How do I set floating timezone on iOS calendar?

Tags: ios, calendar, timezone

I have long ago discovered that if I want to keep calendar event times in the local time zone to set the time zone as floating. In reality, that’s no time zone at all. This really important when scheduling flights.

This is easy enough to do in the Calendar app on macOS. It’s also easy to do if I construct VCALENDAR events manually. In either case, it works well on my iPhone (or iPad).

The problem is that I can’t find a way to do this from iOS itself. The timezone options don’t include floating, which means that though I can add an event on my iPhone, I have to go to a Mac to finish the job.

Is there a way to set the timezone to floating / remove the timezone on iOS? From the Calendar app, a third party app, a shortcut or even some code in Swift?

**Edit:**

A simple workaround is t create a dummy event on the Mac with a floating timezone. On the iPhone, I can then copy and paste as many times as I like.